# tmux vs GNU screen display

Tags: tmux

I want to know the display difference between tmux and GNU screen.
sorry that I don't know how to search it in google, so I ask it here first.

In GNU screen, after exiting vim, what vim displayed stays there, uncleared.
but in tmux, after exiting vim, the screen is repainted, returning to the original place where I started vim.

I want to know what the two display style are called. so I can search it for more information.

PS:
in fact, this difference bothers me; because in tmux when i am browsing code in vim, ctlr+] and ":cs find" are of great value. but they usually give a lot of items, sometimes exceeding the height of my monitor.

Let's take 100 items for the output of "cs find" for example.
in GNU screen, I can let it to show all the 100 items and enter the search mode and search back for what i am looking for.
but in tmux, after finishing showing the 100 items and entering the search mode, I find that the output is truncated and the first part of the 100 items are missing, which is not good for my search within the output of ctrl+] or "cs find".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After searching and asking a lot on the internet, I finally come to my answer, the function that i mentioned in my question is *smcup/rmcup*.